# php using "Content-Disposition:attachment; and Content-type:application/octet stream, gives "/n"

Tags: header

> $file_name="test.key";       $key="1111111";
>   header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
>   header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");    echo trim($key);

the above listed is my piece of code but when this is called, when opening the document, I am having to new lines before "11111111".

May I know, how to avoid new line space, is this an issue or am I using wrong headers,

Here the scenario is I'll get the key from the database and give that key as a download option.

Thanks in advance